# Compilation Instructions for gptoolbox (Mex)

Tags: matlab, mex, toolbox

I Use matlab R2023a in windows 10. try to install GPtoolbox.
i Download Visual Studio 2019, Download boost, CMake,  git and Intel oneMKL from. first, clone gptoolbox (git clone https://github.com/alecjacobson/gptoolbox/) and gptoolbox file create as same address as Boost.
when i type
(cd gptoolbox/mex
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..)
in Windows Powershell i got this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGJMR.png)

.The second method to make sure of my installations is correct
I use Cmake_Gui and copy paste the path as (C:/dev/gptoolbox/mex) in  "where is the source code"
and (C:/dev/gptoolbox/mex/build) for where to build the binaries?
when hit configure again i got error that:

**CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
Running

'nmake' '-?'

failed with:

The system cannot find the file specified

CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
**

Comment: Ask them, in the repo.